# What does MethodImplOptions.Synchronized do?

Tags: .net, multithreading

What does `MethodImplOptions.Synchronized` do?

Is the code below

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void Method()
{
    MethodImpl();
}
```

equivalent to

```
public void Method()
{
    lock(this)
    {
        MethodImpl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This was answered by [Mr. Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) on another [site](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/253333-does-methodimpl-methodimploptions-synchronized-lock-entire-object#post1021344).

Quote from Post

> It's the equivalent to putting lock(this) round the whole method call.

The post has more example code.

Comment: That's true for instance methods and properties, but for static ones it locks on the type, which [goes against best practice](http://michaelprimeaux.com/blog/2008/01/09/methodimploptions-dot-synchronized/) and actually has a known [bug on x64 systems](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/423280/methodimpl-methodimploptions-synchronized-intermittently-throws-synchronizationlockexception-when-used-on-static-method-on-x64) that causes Object synchronization exceptions to be thrown.

Comment: Strangely enough, it looks like any field created on a user-made Control are silently emitted as properties with this attribute when Winforms is used with VB.NET (it does not happen in C#). I have not found a way to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 8):

For static methods it's the same as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Method()
    {
        lock(typeof(MyClass))
        {
           MethodImpl();
        }
    }
}
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6a72e00-d4cc-4f29-a6a0-b27551f78b9b/methodimploptionssynchronized-vs-lock

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is.
See [MethodImplOptions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx)