# How do I change one operation to ConcurrencyMode=single?

Tags: wcf

**This is my service:**

```
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple
```

I have one method that returns an ID by searching something at the service computer. This method can't be act like ConcurrencyMode.Multiple. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a service that uses `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` but you also want a method that is single threaded.

Just use locking in the service method

```
private object getIdLock = new object();
public int GetId()
{
    lock(getIdLock)
    {
        // do your stuff in here
    }
}
```

Comment: but what heppends to the aother clients that cant get in to that lock? Do they wait until the first one is finished?

Comment: Or even put [`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223656/what-does-methodimploptions-synchronized-do) on the method, then you can never accidentally go outside the lock.

Comment: [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] is bad practice and should be avoided as it can easily lead to deadlocks if someone locks on your service object. This attribute is essentially a lock(this) on the entire method. See the note on the MSDN documentation page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx

Comment: @StavAlfi Yes, only 1 thread (1 client with your config) can run the lock block at a time

Comment: [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] locks all my service so no client can even use aother methods. this is not a good solution. by the way, puting the property getIDlock in the service is a bit ugly. is there something else?

Comment: @StavAlfi No, using the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] will just lock methods that also declare the attribute, methods not declaring the attribute are not impacted

Comment: [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] = lock(this) = if one client use this method, while he is using it , no other client can use my service until the first client end that method.

Comment: @StavAlfi No thats wrong, your other methods will not need to acquire a lock on the object to run

Comment: Why not? I locked the all object from any client.