# How to ensure a certain method doesn't get executed if some other method is running?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Let's say I have two methods -

```
getCurrentValue(int valueID)
updateValues(int changedComponentID)
```

These two methods are called on the same object independently by separate threads.

`getCurrentValue()` simply does a database look-up for the current valueID.

"`Values`" change if their corresponding `components` change. The `updateValues()`method updates those values that are dependent upon the component that just changed, i.e. `changedComponentID`. This is a database operation and takes time.

While this update operation is going on, I do not want to return a stale value by doing a lookup from the database, but I want to wait till the update method has completed. At the same time, I don't want two update operations to happen simultaneously or an update to happen when a read is going on.

So, I'm thinking of doing it this way -

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public int getCurrentValue(int valueID)
     {
        while(updateOperationIsGoingOn)
          {
             // do nothing  
          }
        readOperationIsGoingOn = true;

        value = // read value from DB

        readOperationIsGoingOn = false; 
        return value;
     }

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void updateValues(int componentID)
     {
         while(readOperationIsGoingOn)
          {
             // do nothing
          }
         updateOperationIsGoingOn = true;

         // update values in DB

         updateOperationIsGoingOn = false;
     }
```

I'm not sure whether this is a correct way of doing it. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: you need to use lock() instead of wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the correct way. Like this you are doing an "active wait", effectively blocking your CPU.

You should use a lock instead:

```
static object _syncRoot = new object();
public int getCurrentValue(int valueID)
{
    lock(_syncRoot)
    {
        value = // read value from DB
    }
}

public void updateValues(int componentID)
{
    lock(_syncRoot)
    {
        // update values in DB
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this technique called? Semaphores?

Comment: +1: This is one of 2 way of fixing the code... The second is to simply remove all `readOperationIsGoingOn` stuff and rely on lock automatically generated for Synchronized -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223656/what-does-methodimploptions-synchronized-do

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov. I am in effect trying to lock the whole object with the "readOperationIsGoing" on stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Create a static object outside of both of these methods.  Then use a lock statement on that object; when one method is accessing the protected code, the other method will wait for the lock to release.

```
private static object _lockObj = new object();

public int getCurrentValue(int valueID)
     {
        object value;

        lock(_lockObj)
          {
           value = // read value from DB
          }
        return value;
     }

public void updateValues(int componentID)
     {
         lock(_lockObj)
          {
         // update values in DB

          }
     }
```

Comment: My apologies, forgot to delete the attributes.

Comment: +1 - now looks fine - either attriute or manual locking - both is overkill.

Comment: Agreed; however, in case of nested locks, the CLR only enters the lock once - so  behind the scenes, the behavior is the same :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static readonly object _lock = new object();

public int getCurrentValue(int valueID)
{
    try
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_lock);
        value = // read value from DB
        return value;
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lock);
    }
}

public void updateValues(int componentID)
{
    try
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_lock);
        // update values in DB
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lock);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's this monitor lizard about? An alternative way of locking as compared to the other answers?

Comment: +0. Rewriting `lock` by hand is not much of use (also correct).

Comment: I like to use the Monitor pattern because Monitor also provides a TryEnter method that allows a timeout to be specified, either in milliseconds or as a TimeSpan. The method then returns true if a lock was obtained, or false if no lock was obtained because the method timed out. TryEnter can also be called with no argument, which “tests” the lock, timing out immediately if the lock can’t be obtained right away. Just gives me a little bit more control and a few additional options.

Comment: @Kevin: But you are not using `TryEnter`. And you can still use `TryEnter` on a variable used in a `lock` statement. So what you are doing here is useless boilerplate code.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgrath - granted, I did not use TryEnter in this case, but I like to keep the option available. Just looked up the Lock class in MSDN and didn't see any mention of a TryEnter functionality if you are using it. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Daniel Hilgrath - I misread what you were saying about the TryEnter, while it is true that you can mix and match (use Lock in some places and Monitor.TryEnter on the same object in others) I like to have some consistancy in the patterns I use in code where I can (just a personal preference). And while I grant that my code is a bit more verbose than using the Lock class, I truely don't think that it adds so much as to be classifiable as "useless biolerplate" code.

Comment: @Kevin: I am not talking about a `Lock` class. I am talking about the `lock` keyword (see my answer). It will be expanded by the compiler to code very similar to yours. Explicitly writing that out doesn't add value which makes it - at least for me - useless boilerplate code. This is comparable to not using `foreach` and instead enumerating the enumerator yourself via `MoveNext` and `Current`.