# C# restrict one static call each time in a class with 100+ static method

Tags: c#

I have a class with ***100+-*** public static method and I want to restrict one static call each time ,is there any trick of achieving this with ***a few line of code?***
Like some class attribute to achieve this?

Like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void A() { }
    public static void B() { }
    public static void C() { }
    public static void D() { }
}
```

Only one static method call be access at one time. When method B is calling , the call to other method must be blocked until method B return;

**Sorry, It seem that I have post some misleading title. My real purpose is to find a way to reduce coding to achieve the result the same with which by adding *lock* statement to every function.**

---

#### Solved

I solved the problem by adding *lock* statment to every function at last, but using the following macro to do the repeat job for me.

```
''
'' edit from Code outlining sample.
''
Sub LoopFunction()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fileCM As FileCodeModel
    Dim elts As EnvDTE.CodeElements
    Dim elt As EnvDTE.CodeElement

    fileCM = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel
    elts = fileCM.CodeElements
    For i = 1 To elts.Count
        elt = elts.Item(i)
        EditFunction(elt)
    Next
End Sub

Sub EditFunction(ByVal elt As EnvDTE.CodeElement)

    If (elt.Kind = EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) Then
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim mems As EnvDTE.CodeElements

        mems = elt.Members
        For i = 1 To mems.Count
            EditFunction(mems.Item(i))
        Next
    ElseIf (elt.Kind = vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass) Then
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim mems As EnvDTE.CodeElements

        mems = elt.Members
        For i = 1 To mems.Count
            EditFunction(mems.Item(i))
        Next
    ElseIf (elt.Kind = vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction) Then
        Dim epStart As EnvDTE.EditPoint
        Dim epEnd As EnvDTE.EditPoint
        Dim textSelection As EnvDTE.TextSelection

        epStart = elt.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartBody).CreateEditPoint()
        epEnd = elt.GetEndPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartBody).CreateEditPoint()
        textSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        textSelection.MoveToPoint(epEnd)
        textSelection.Insert(NewLine & "}" & NewLine)
        textSelection.MoveToPoint(epStart)
        textSelection.Insert(NewLine & "lock(lockTest){" & NewLine)

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Use [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] attribute on the method. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223656/what-does-methodimploptions-synchronized-do)

Comment: @DarrenKopp Thanks. But I want to prevent calling different static method at the same time  ,not just one method.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead thanks for your time . I just edit the original post.

Comment: Are you talking about multithreaded access or nested calls?

Comment: Look at the docs, MethodImplOptions.Synchronized would lock all methods marked with that attribute since it locks on the type.

Comment: @SimonMourier my class is used to wrap unmanaged dll.

Comment: @DarrenKopp thanks. I solved it using the other method. thank you all the same.

Comment: What are your methods like? Are they short and do similar things? Are they all parameter-less?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for your time .No , I solved the problem anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following attribute to each static method:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
```

For static methods, this is equivalent to placing the following construct in each static method:

```
lock (typeof(Test))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Static object that can only be instantiated once per class
private readonly static lockObj = new object();

 public static void A() {
     lock(lockObj){
       //.. your code here
     }
    }

 public static void B() {
     lock(lockObj){
       //.. your code here
     }
    }

  public static void C() {
     lock(lockObj){
       //.. your code here
     }
    }

  public static void D() {
     lock(lockObj){
       //.. your code here
     }
    }
```

The idea is to create a static object that can be instantiated only once (via readonly keyword), and add lock statements on that static object in all methods which are to be executed one at a time

Comment: I'd consider upvoting this is it contained more than just code. How about some text to explain this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be reduced to a simple Critical Section Problem where each static function have critical code, and only one function at a time should run.
Now you can use any standard method for solving this problem like semaphore. Acquire lock before executing a function and release lock after execution, so that other function which are waiting can execute.
Binary semaphore will do the job in your case.