# Class-level locking

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a class with some static methods. These static methods work with same resource (a Data List). I want this data list to be thread safe. Since number of static methods in same class are working with same data list. I can't simply use lock/Monitor to secure my code in multithreading environment. How can I ensure that only one thread is executing any method of my class and other threads should wait for this thread to exit no matter they want to run the same method or different method in my class. How can I achieve this?
Here is some code to clarify. My Job is to write the `MyLibraryClass`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      
        var t1 =System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(MyLibraryClass.A);

        var t2 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(MyLibraryClass.B);

        t1.Wait();
        t2.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Completed. Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

class MyLibraryClass
{

    static List<int> items = new List<int>();
    static MyLibraryClass()
    {
        items.Add(5);
        items.Add(4);
    }
    public static void A()
    {
        foreach (var a in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
    }

    public static void B()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("Adding Number");
        items.Add(9);
    }
}
```

Comment: `How can I ensure that only one thread is executing any method of my class...` - by not using multi-threading

Comment: Put a lock block inside all of those methods that works on one and the same `private static readonly object _lock = new object();` in all cases...? :) Although using multithreading with such class is pointless, as you will be forcing sequential execution.

Comment: @DGibbs a rather flippant statement sir. The OP may be writing code to be used by other engineers. The code may even be the product. It will certainly want to ensure call serialization if concurrency can cause an issue.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek it is pretty rare that the shared resource is the **only** thing that is going on, so it is very much not "pointless"

Comment: @MarcGravell True enough, but static, mutable data in multithreaded environment makes my skin crawl when I even think about it.

Comment: As the @Gusdor said, there are situations when u have to run some part of your multithreading logic to be run in sequential. As in my case, My task is composed of multiple sub tasks.Sub tasks can run in parallel and I can gain benefit in running them parallel, except this sub-task which should be run in sequential. It is like all parallel results are converging to a single class which executes code in sequential and once processed, Threads can continue to run the output in parallel. Also my task is atomic so I can't exempt this sequential part from my task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't simply use lock/Monitor to secure my code in multithreading environment.

Yes you can. That is **exactly** what you are meant to do.

> How can I ensure that only one thread is executing any method of my class and other threads should wait for this thread to exit no matter they want to run the same method or different method in my class. How can I achieve this?

By using `lock`/`Monitor`. Or some other threading metaphor, such as a thread-safe collection but `lock` is the simplest. Thread-safe collections require more thinking when you are dealing with atomic units that are actually multiple operations (test then add if missing, for example).

Another tip would be: don't use static lists of mutable data : it is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: lock/monitor ensure that code block will be executed by one thread at a time. But my problem is not protecting a single code block. I have two methods A and B. If a Thread T1 wants to execute Method A and Thread T2 wants to execute method B then T1 and T2 should not run those methods in parallel. T2 can run method B only if T1 has finished running method A.

Comment: @ZafarYousafi Methods A and B should establish a lock upon the same member.

Comment: @ZafarYousafi - that is not a logical requirement. Thread-safety is always about protecting data (state), never about methods.

Comment: @Gusdor you don't have to hold the lock for the entire method - just the bits where you access the shared data.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It is logical. I am not talking about method safety. I am talking about data safety. But these methods are working on the same data. It is like method A is adding in the list based on some complex logic and method B is removing based on some logic.And this logic demands data list not to be modified

Comment: @ZafarYousafi then you need those two operations to be synchronized from each other. So you need to use something like a `lock`...

Comment: @MarcGravell It is possible only if I have control over creating threads and calling these methods, which unfortunately I don't have.

Comment: @ZafarYousafi if you don't have control over the methods that are accessing the shared state, you are "SOL", and need to consider some kind of refactor that considers thread-safety from the outset. You might have *some* luck with thread-safe collections, but these aren't a magic bullet (the classic example being "check if in list, then add"). Another alternative would be: stop using mutable shared state.

Comment: @ZafarYousafi and again, nothing changes; you have the same options: 1: use `lock` inside the methods, for the specific bits that talk to state - which you say is not an option; 2: use `lock` in whatever *calls* the methods, and accept that the entire methods will be synchronized from eachother, or 3: use a thread-safe collection but understand that any code that makes decisions based on the state of the collection (rather than simply adding, etc) is inherently buggy and susceptible to a thread race, or 4: refactor the code properly such that the code doesn't talk to the shared state directly

Comment: oops. Importance of object passed to lock/monitor was not clear to me until now. Now It is clear that lock gives lock on the instance provided and not on the enclosed code block only. Thanks @Marc for bearing my silly arguments with patience.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [synchronization] attribute for your MyLibraryClass. That will ensure the whole class is thread safe.

Comment: The [`SynchronizationAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.synchronizationattribute) is only for .NET Framework and Xamarin applications. For general usage there is the [`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223656/what-does-methodimploptions-synchronized-do).