# WCF failure leads to high thread count

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm currently sending information via WCF to 2 endpoints. On occassion one endpoint is stopped for maintaince. During this time I see my sending application thread count increase. When the endpoint is restarted (hours or days later) it will receive a flood of calls and the thread count on the sending application will return to normal. I'm using the following netTCPBinding but I dont see how the sending application is buffering these requests (and thus growing its thread count). I do use Parallel.ForEach when sending the information to the 2 endpoints.

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="HANetTcp" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:00:05"> 
      <security mode="None"/> 
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

Comment: So, what's the exact problem? Does the thread count have a practical effect?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yea, it kills the application as it can and does consume the services whole threadpool if the endpoint if offline longer than a few hours. What I'm trying to find is the root cause of this.

Comment: Since you use `Parallel.ForEach`, I would begin by assuming that this is your problem.

Comment: Yea, using it with ConcurrentBag which has quiet a few posts here also but nothing that would cause a buffer to be kept but its possible a thread reference may be getting held somewhere. Trying to identify is very difficult though.

Comment: What happens when you don't use `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Removed all references to Parallel and suffering the same issue.

Comment: @JohnSaunders root cause was TimerCallback usage with MethodImplOptions.Synchronized which was somehow holding thread references (not always but enough to exhaust the thread pool)

Answer (score 1):

Root cause was TimerCallback usage with MethodImplOptions.Synchronized which was somehow holding thread references (not always but enough to exhaust the thread pool) –

Comment: Yeah, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223656/what-does-methodimploptions-synchronized-do. Suggestion: "don't _do_ that".