# Critical Section Web API

Tags: c#, synchronization, locking

I am creating a endpoint that creates a new user.  Two request are sent to the end point at the same time, two users will be created. How do I protect this critical section? I tried using "[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]"  however it does not prevent two threads to enter into the critical section.

```
   User user = db.User.Where(u => u.FbId.Equals(userObject.fbid)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)     // critical section
        {
          // create user and save it to database
          db.SaveChanges();
       }
```

Comment: Hint : use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx on class

Comment: Why would it be a problem for ocde to enter that critical section at the same time?

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223656/what-does-methodimploptions-synchronized-do says the effect will be identical - 2 requests still can run in parallel because there are new controllers for each request. Note that OP's statement about "does not prevent two threads..." is not directly related to the problem and indeed 2 threads would not be able to call the same method on *the same object* with code mentioned by OP.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov - I was reffering to the lock statement (on the controller class), and this will prevent the parallel thread execution

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican I see. You mean to follow "don't do that" recommendation in the article - "In general, avoid locking on a public type .... The common constructs `(typeof (MyType))` ... violate this guideline" - That could work indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are assigning Ids in your code (bad idea) rather than automatically by your database server, but if you did want to have a critical section, to me it looks like your code would work in parallel and you would not get any duplicate ids if you used autoassigned IDs or GUIDs as IDs :

Each request from the web browser is processed by a separate thread. This can either be threads running under one process, or if you go into settings in IIS, you can change your application to run under multiple processes.

If eventually the app is deployed to Azure cloud, the threads might not run even on the same machine. This has implications for the use of Lock and alternatively Global Mutex. Lock is a process only mutex, so will only work with since process multiple thread scenario. 
Global mutex with run in multiple process multiple thread. But if running on multiple geographically distributed machines across the web, you need to either have a special single machine that is running with global Mutex, or use someone else's prerolled global mutex - like use a database server's lock and unlock functions for example. using GUIDs for Ids would mean no requirement for a mutex, so in theory for huge volume system is faster.